# Implement a Java Iterator for a nested HashMap in which an element can be any of 1) an Integer or, 2) another nested HashMap or, 3) an empty HashMap

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

As described in the title, how can we do this? I feel that it should be something similar to a tree traversal, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

```
    Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();     

    map.put(1, 1);
    map.put(2, 2);


    map.put(3, new HashMap<Integer, Object>());
    Map<Integer, Object> m1 = (Map<Integer, Object>)map.get(3);
    m1.put(4, 4);
    m1.put(5, new HashMap<Integer, Object>());      
    m1.put(6, 6);

    Map<Integer, Object> m2 = (Map<Integer, Object>)m1.get(5);
    m2.put(8, 8);
    m2.put(9, 9);

    map.put(7, new HashMap<Integer, Object>());
```

In this example, the first two "values" are two Integers, and the third "value" is a nested HashMap which contains two Integers and one "deeper level" nested HashMap. Regarding key 7, I would like to express that the "value" can also be an empty HashMap -- because this is an interview question, I guess this possibility of having "empty value" may affect the next() or hasNext() implementation?

Comment: things are simple until you try to address them, put in your effort and am sure, you will com up with some logic. share your effort and we will help, when you are stuck.

Comment: `HashMap` contain a `key` - `value` pair. So how do you define an element in your question? Is it `Integer` as `key` and `HashMap` as `value`?

Comment: Sorry, here element I mean a value..

Comment: More details: for each key-value pair in the nested HashMap, key is always an Integer, and value can be any of 1) an Integer, 2) another nested HashMap, or 3) an empty HashMap.  --- and the purpose of the Iterator would be to output all the Integer "values" if you keep calling the next() function. --- Hope this clarify is clear...

Comment: How are you able to declare such a `HashMap`? Could you post how you declare the `HashMap`? Also when you are answering any comment use @<username> to notify that person immediately.

Comment: @Blip OK, thanks. I've added an example.

Comment: edit your code and post the example

Comment: @Blip please see the question body, thanks.

Comment: had you posted this at the first you would not have got the down vote. Well let me see how I can help you out.

Comment: I feel that your `map.put(7, new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());` should be `map.put(7, m1);`

Comment: @Blip Hi, I edited the example a little bit, in this example, the first two "values" are two Integers, and the third "value" is a nested HashMap which contains two Integers and one "deeper level" nested HashMap.  Regarding key 7, I would like to express that the "value" can also be an empty HashMap -- because this is an interview question, I guess this possibility of having "empty value" may affect the next() or hasNext() implementation?

Comment: It would be more helpful for every one If you posted the previous comment directed to me in the question itself.

Comment: @Blip thanks, I've added this to the question body...

Comment: It will take some time but I will definitely come back to you with some good suggestions.

Comment: @Blip sure, no rush, thanks. My friend encountered this question in his onsite interview (and failed to get an offer because he did not solve this in 45 minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually many different solutions to this.
By far the shortest one is this here, which uses Streams.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> Stream<T> mapTraversalStream(Map<Integer, T> map) {
  return map.values().stream().flatMap(value -> {
    if(value instanceof Map) {
      return mapTraversalStream((Map<Integer, T>)value);
    } else {
      return Stream.of(value);
    }
  });
}

static <T> Iterator<T> mapTraversalIterator(Map<Integer, T> map) {
  return mapTraversalStream(map).iterator();
}
```

edit:

If you can't use Java 8 you could define your own map and flatten methods.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> Iterator<T> mapTraversalIterator(Map<Integer, T> map) {
  return flatten(map(map.values().iterator(), new Function<T, Iterator<T>>() {
      public Iterator<T> apply(T value) {
        if(value instanceof Map) {
          return mapTraversalIterator((Map<Integer, T>)value);
        } else {
          return Collections.singleton(value).iterator();
        }
      }
  }));
}

interface Function<A, B> {
  B apply(A a);
}

static <A, B> Iterator<B> map(Iterator<A> iter, Function<A, B> op) {
  return new Iterator<B>() {
    public boolean hasNext() {
      return iter.hasNext();
    }
    public B next() {
      return op.apply(iter.next());
    }
  };
}

static <A> Iterator<A> flatten(Iterator<Iterator<A>> iter) {
  return new Iterator<A>() {
    private Iterator<A> next = null;

    public boolean hasNext() {
      while(iter.hasNext() && (next == null || !next.hasNext())) {
        next = iter.next();
      }
      if(next == null || !next.hasNext()) return false;
      else return true;
    }
    public A next() {
      if(!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
      return next.next();
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do this without using Java 8 new features?

Comment: Sure, I added an example to my answer.